# core data - entity help

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am currently receiving an error of -

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Invoices''

How this came about:

I set up an Entity and Attributes called 'Friends'. I am successfully using Fetch Request to get and display the data I want. The next stage of development for me was to add another Entity called 'Invoices' with various attributes. I added this to the datamodel and added a new fetch request to reflect this.

I have tried to reset the iPhone simulator, and added a new version, changed current version, and changed back to try and clear the error, but no joy.

The app crashes when it gets to this line of code:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Invoices" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI - I have not made any relationship between 'Friends' and 'Invoices' entitys

Comment: Is your datamodel in a separate app, such as a static library ? Anyway I had this error because the .momd file was not included in the main app bundle. Therefore the context could not be initialized. How do you load your data model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your build target to make sure that your are using the model file you think you are using.

Sometimes and old complied `.momd` file will not be removed from the simulator when you change the model file. Completely deleting the app off the simulator, doing a clean on the project and rebuilding usually fixes the problem.

However, the most common cause of this error is a simple typo e.g. using `Invoice` for `Invoices` or vice versa.